# make_uniqueの利点

Tags: c++

現在C++を勉強中なのですが、unique_ptrの使い方でわからないことがあります。
オブジェクトのポインタを渡して、unique_ptrを生成する際、C++14であればヘルパー関数を使うことができると思います。しかし、そのままnewを使う場合と比べてヘルパー関数を使う利点がわかりません。

例えば、下記の1点目と比較して、2点目はどのような利点があるのでしょうか？

- `std::unique_ptr<int> pInt {new int{1}};`
- `std::unique_ptr<int> pInt {std::make_unique<int>(1)};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::unique_ptr<int> pInt {new int{1}}; // (1)
```

と

```
std::unique_ptr<int> pInt {std::make_unique<int>(1)};  // (2)
```

の大きな違いは、`unique_ptr<int>` のインスタンスを作るのに、(1) では `new int{1}` が呼ばれてから、`unique_ptr<int>` のコンストラクタが呼ばれるという風に、2段階で処理が行われるのに対し、(2) では、`std::make_unique<int>(1)` を呼ぶだけで作られるということです。

例えば

```
class A;

void f(std::unique_ptr<A> p1, std::unique_ptr<A> p2);
```

という関数があったときに、

```
f(std::unique_ptr<A>{new A{0}}, std::unique_ptr<A>{new A{1}}); // (3)
```

と呼び出したとします。ここで生成された二つの A のインスタンスは、`unique_ptr` になるので、きちんと解放されるように見えます。しかし、実は解放されないケースがありうるのです。

C++ では、関数の引数の評価の順番は未規定です。(3) の場合だと

1. `new A{0}`
2. `new A{1}`
3. 1 で生成した A のインスタンスを用いて、一番目の `std::unique_ptr<A>` を生成
4. 2 で生成した A のインスタンスを用いて、二番目の `std::unique_ptr<A>` を生成
5. `f()` の呼び出し

という順番で評価しても構わないのです。このとき 2. で A のコンストラクタが例外を投げると、1. で生成された A のインスタンスは、まだunique_ptr になっていないので、リークしてしまいます。

ここで `std::make_unique` を使えば、

```
f(std::make_unique<A>(0), std::make_unique<A>(1)); // (4)
```

1. `std::make_unique<A>(0)` で一番目の `unique_ptr<A>` を生成
2. `std::make_unique<A>(1)` で二番目の `unique_ptr<A>` を生成
3. `f()` の呼び出し

となり、`new A{1}` が例外を発生する物であっても、メモリリークを起こすことがありません。

Comment: **関数の引数の評価の順番は未規定**なのはわかりますが、第１引数の式を評価している途中で第２引数の式を評価することが許されるのでしょうか？ 仮に許されるとして、第１引数の`make_unique`評価途中で第２引数の`make_unique`の評価が行われないことは規定されているのでしょうか？

Comment: @sayuri  この説明は Effective Modern C++ を参考にしています (item: 21 - この本の中では make_shared を使っていますが)。C++ 仕様書のドラフト n4527 の 1.9 Program execution のところを、ざっと読んでみましたが、関数を呼び出す前にすべての引数が評価されていることだけが条件のようです。`std::make_unique<A>(0)` 自体は、ただの関数呼び出し、つまり関数内で `unique_ptr` が作られるので、大丈夫です。

Comment: +1: なお、sayuriさんコメントにある「第１引数の式を評価している途中で第２引数の式を評価すること」は仕様上許容され、「第１引数のmake_unique評価途中で第２引数のmake_uniqueの評価が行われないこと」もまた明示的に保証されています。C++11 1.9/paragraph 15参照。

Answer (score 5):

`make_unique`を使用するとコンストラクター呼び出しではなくなるので`auto`変数が使えます。対して`std::unique_ptr`はコンストラクター呼び出しなので型名を省略できません。

```
std::unique_ptr<int> pInt {new int{1}};
auto pInt = std::make_unique<int>(1);
```

また前者は`std::unique_ptr`でポインター管理され自動的に`delete`されるとは言え、ソースコードの見た目上は`new`しておいて`delete`していないという非対称な構造になってしまいます。`make_unique`であればそのようなことにはなりません。

---

逆に`make_unique`はカスタム`Deleter`を指定できないという欠点があります。